# How to update tables with in date range

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

Work on sql server 2008 r2. Want to join table=**ValueTable** and table= **DateRangeTable** .Both table data as like as picture .There is no strong relation between them ,Need to update **ValueTable** column  on range of **DateRangeTable** column **StartDate** and **EndDate**.

[image]

If have any query please ask ,Any type of suggestion will be acceptable,thanks in advanced.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this and let me know your comments/Results

```
UPDATE ValueTable SET IncRange=DRT.IncRange
FROM ValueTable VT INNER JOIN DaatRangeTable DRT ON VT.BillDate >= DRT.StartDate AND VT.BillDate <=DRT.EndDate
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use an `update...select` query like below

```
update ValueTable
set ValueTable.incRange = drt.incRange
from DateRangeTable drt 
where ValueTable.BillDate >= drt.StartDate and ValueTable.BillDate <= drt.EndDate
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Select * from DateRangeTable inner join ValueTable on 
MONTH(BillDate)=DateRangeTable.MonthNumber
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use BETWEEN clause as well.

```
UPDATE ValueTable
SET    ValueTable.incRange = DateRangeTable.incRange
FROM   ValueTable, DateRangeTable 
WHERE  ValueTable.BillDate BETWEEN DateRangeTable.StartDate AND ValueTable.BillDate
```